# Bootstrap 3 RC1 responsive fluid grid system breakpoint issues

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have designed a website to just for testing the Bootstrap 3 RC1.
I have 4 grid in a row(12 grid / 4 =col-3) and when I tried to Minimize it to Small-Display the area of grids-row are not going to second line but it has scaling-up to the same row.

my site : http://goo.gl/zcn8ri

For example below is my code, I have used class="col-2 col-sm-1 col-lg-3", so what I need is in Large display the grid will should display as it is '3-Col' and for small display it should be 2 Col(line-break) but its not happening ...

```
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-2 col-sm-1 col-lg-3">
      <div class="pc-area">
        <center>
          <a href="#"><span class="area-positions"><img src="images/pc-laptop.png" alt="PC Laptop"></span></a>
        </center>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-2 col-sm-1 col-lg-3">
      <div class="mac-area">
        <center>
          <a href="#"><span class="area-positions"><img src="images/mac-macbook.png" alt="Mac"></span></a>
        </center>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-2 col-sm-1 col-lg-3">
      <div class="iphone-area">
        <center>
          <a href="#"><span class="area-positions"><img src="images/iphone.png" alt="iPhone"></span></a>
        </center>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-2 col-sm-1 col-lg-3">
      <div class="ipad-area">
        <center>
          <a href="#"><span class="area-positions"><img src="images/ipad.png" alt="iPads"></span></a>
        </center>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Also my background is not looking good in small display.

please suggest.

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1):

Just remove col-2 and do like below

```
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-3 col-lg-3">
      <div class="pc-area item">
        <center>
          <a href="#"><span class="area-positions"><img src="images/pc-laptop.png" class="img-responsive" alt="PC Laptop"></span></a>
        </center>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3 col-lg-3">
      <div class="mac-area item">
        <center>
          <a href="#"><span class="area-positions"><img src="images/mac-macbook.png"  class="img-responsive"  alt="Mac"></span></a>
        </center>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3 col-lg-3">
      <div class="iphone-area item">
        <center>
          <a href="#"><span class="area-positions"><img src="images/iphone.png"  class="img-responsive"  alt="iPhone"></span></a>
        </center>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3 col-lg-3">
      <div class="ipad-area item">
        <center>
          <a href="#"><span class="area-positions"><img src="images/ipad.png"  class="img-responsive"  alt="iPads"></span></a>
        </center>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Also in your CSS

```
.pc-area {
    background: url(images/pc-laptop-area.png) no-repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
    min-height: 225px;
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
.mac-area {
    background: url(images/mac-area.png) no-repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
    min-height: 225px;
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
.iphone-area {
    background: url(images/iphone-area.png) no-repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
    min-height: 225px;
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
.ipad-area {
    background: url(images/ipad-area.png) no-repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
    min-height: 225px;
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
.ipod-area {
    background: url(images/ipod-area.png) no-repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
    min-height: 225px;
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    }
.galaxy-area {
    background: url(images/galaxy-area.png) no-repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
    min-height: 225px;
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
.macpro-area {
    background: url(images/macpro-area.png) no-repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
    min-height: 225px;
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    }
.business-area {
    background: url(images/web-business-area.png) no-repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
    min-height: 225px;
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```

So that for Medium layout it will looks great and it would be better not to put image text into those pallets...